# PayPal Sandbox - Error 10002: You do not have permission to make this API call

Tags: php, api, paypal

I'm trying to use the PayPal API for express checkout using PHP. I used [this guide](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php) as a template. When connecting, I receive the error message:

```
[TIMESTAMP] => 2015%2d07%2d20T15%3a32%3a37Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 3a93310587276
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 109%2e0
[BUILD] => 17403434
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Authentication%2fAuthorization%20Failed
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You%20do%20not%20have%20permissions%20to%20make%20this%20API%20call
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
```

The error has no correction listed in the errorcode doc: 
developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/

Upon further research into the error, I read [here](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN19342.html) that you must confirm your email on your paypal account, which I have. Since I'm using a sandbox api account, I also attempted to confirm it, however when I try to from the notifications panel under sandbox test accounts, and I copy/paste the confirmation link into my browser, it tells me the confirmation code is invalid, even if I paste it into the input field. But if I log into the sandbox site with the sandbox account whose email I'm trying to confirm, and when I click confirm in the email section on the email which failed to confirm before, it now says it's already confirmed. Still receiving the above error though.

I've made sure to use the sandbox account api credentials when configuring the connection. It's also a business-pro sandbox account, and the endpoint is for sandbox.

Is there anything obvious that I've missed?

Is there anything additional I should post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different reasons that you would get that message. One reason is your credentials are incorrect, make certain there are no spaces in your credentials.

Another reason for that error message could be related to the endpoint you are using. If you are using Sandbox API, make certain you are using the Sandbox Endpoint.

If you are using Live API credentials make certain that you are pointed at the Live Endpoint.
[API Error codes PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/#id09C3E1009E9)

[Express Checkout Endpoints](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/#ec)

Another reason, if you are doing a DoDirectPayment Api Call, make certain that the account you are using is setup for PayPal Payments Pro.

Comment: The problem was a stupid mistake on my end, I included the config(i.e credentials) out of the scope my payment function. So technically yes, the credentials were the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You simply dont have acess to the api, they need to give you a token(in this case called Signature) to you acess PayPal API. You probably need to check you email adress, if that doesnt work just register again on the Paypal Developers :)

Comment: hoo yeah and you need to have the right 

$PayPalMode         = 'sandbox'; // sandbox or live
$PayPalApiUsername  = 'selleremail@somesite.com'; //PayPal API Username
$PayPalApiPassword  = '123456'; //Paypal API password

Comment: I've already done this
`I've made sure to use the sandbox account api credentials when configuring the connection. It's also a business-pro sandbox account, and the endpoint is for sandbox.`